# Does there exist a integer solution to a consistent linear system consisting of only $1$s and $0$s?

Tags: systems-of-equations, integers

Say I have a coefficient matrix $M_{m \times n}, n>m$. The only values in the coefficient matrix are $1$s and $0$s.

I have a vector of constants $V_{n \times 1}$ consisting only of positive integers.

If it is shown that the linear system $MX = V$ is consistent, then does that immediately follow that there are integer solutions for $X$? (i.e does solutions in Real Numbers imply integer solutions?)

I have a gut feeling it does, but I can't find a way to prove it.

Also, if the above is fulfilled, and  there are no two rows i,j  where:

Every single index where $M[i]$ has $1$ is also $1$ in $M[j]$, and  $M[j]$ contains $1$s not in $M[i]$, and $V[j] < V[i]$

(i.e The set of indices where $M[i]$ is $1$ is a proper subset of the  set of indices where $M[j]$ is $1$ and $V[j]< V[i]$)

e.g :

$$M[i] = (1,1,0,0,0)$$
$$M[j]= (1,1,1,0,0)$$

$$V[i]= 3$$
$$V[j]= 2$$

Does a positive (including zero) integer solution always exist for such a system?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Counterexample: $M=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&\\1&&1\\&1&1\end{bmatrix},v=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Hi Rahul, nice counterexample, but in your case m = n. Is there a counterexample where n > m?

Comment: Ok never mind , I found one.

Comment: Just add a row or column of zeroes, depending on whether you want $m>n$ or $n>m$ :)

Comment: Thank you Rahul.